# Can contagious disease transmitted via sharing things?

Tags: disease-transmission

I wonder is there any chance we can have dangerous contagious disease, such as HIV, herpes, hepatitis, etc via sharing thing with other people?

As I go to fitness center, I share the gym equipment, towel, bath room, steam and sauna room, swimming pool with other people.

If for example, there is a dry blood stain on towel, is it possible to get infected?

Answer (score 1):

HIV will not transmit via sharing things. Except for occasions, such as sharing syringe needles, sharing unmaintained medical equipment.

HIV doesn't always survive in dry blood. (see [this AIDS Map article](http://www.aidsmap.com/Survival-outside-the-body/page/1321278/))

[Hepatitis does](https://www.cdc.gov/ncidod/diseases/hepatitis/c/faq.htm#1b1) (See [this also](https://www.cdc.gov/ncidod/diseases/hepatitis/b/faqb.htm)). So avoid any blood possible. Hepatitis can survive outside human body for up to 7 days. They are tough bugs. They transmit via blood and body fluids

Herpes does transmit via object, but it will not transmit if you touch it by hand. However they will transmit [via mouth and genital parts](http://www.who.int/mediacentre/factsheets/fs400/en/).

Comment: Welcome to Health, many may! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we require answers that are backed up with [reliable](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources) references. Please take the [tour] read the [help], maybe visit some pages from our [meta], like [this](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/a/777/8212).

Comment: https://www.ccohs.ca/oshanswers/biol_hazards/influenza.html spread of influenza through contaminated surfaces

Comment: Needs to be clear that herpes CAN transmit to your hand by touching an active lesion.

Comment: Seems like norovirus deserves a mention here seeing as how it's notoriously transmissible by surfaces.